# How to get max-width to trump min-width?

Tags: css

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

If you shrink your window so that the fiddle is smaller than 200px wide and then inspect the div, you'll see that it's still 200px wide, causing the page to stretch.

Clearly this is because I've set `min-width` to 200px, but I want `max-width` to overrule it. How would I <del>do that</del> emulate this effect?

Comment: Do you have a legitimate use case for designing for screens < 200px or are you just curious if it's possible?  My guess would be this is more of a browser thing in terms of how they choose to render the CSS, but I don't have any sources.

Comment: _"Clearly this is because I've set min-width to 200px, but I want max-width to overrule it. How would I do that?"_ - you would not, because that is impossible - min-width overrules max-width [per specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width). What you do instead, is use a media query to not apply min-width under this condition in the first place.

Comment: @EricDauenhauer Not 200px specifically, but yes I have a use-case for 400-500px or so. Also, the screen wouldn't necessarily need to be that small when you add all the padding from the surrounding divs.

Comment: @CBroe Right, I meant how would I emulate this effect? media-queries are based on screen width. My "100%" isn't equal to the screen width, it's equal to its parent's width.

Comment: Well then you actually want what has been dubbed ["element queries"](https://www.google.de/search?q=element+queries) ...

Answer (score -2):

You can use !important. Normally, CSS code starts reading from the top-left and goes right and down until the end (so the later CSS codes would override the previous ones if there are duplicates) but putting !important overrides that
https://jsfiddle.net/699h51od/

HTML

```
<input type="text"/>
```

CSS

```
input {
  width:500px !important;
}
input {
  width:100px;
}
```